# How to use ProblemDetails class in Blazor

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, nuget, blazor-webassembly

I have a question about using framework references in blazor application.

I am trying to use ProblemsDetails class which is part of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc shared framework. One of the libraries that blazor app reference uses

> <FrameworkReference >

tag in .csproj file.

When I try to build blazor application I get:

```
error NETSDK1082: There was no runtime pack for M 
icrosoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.
```

What's the solution here?

Is there a way to reference ProblemDetails class in blazor and related classes like ValidationProblemDetails?

**Here's library's csproj file:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataLayer\DataLayer.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BizLogic\BizLogic.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="10.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**And here is the blazor wasm .csproj file:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.FluentValidation" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="11.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions" Version="11.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer"
      Version="6.0.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="MudBlazor" Version="6.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ServiceLayer\ServiceLayer.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BizLogic\BizLogic.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I found this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36970

And this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30910

From the previous link I tried to replace framework reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core package.

It appears that referencing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core
resolves the previously mentioned error NETSDK1082.

But instead now I get a different error:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ApplicationPartAttributeA
ttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Here is the code excerpt from the library that uses ProblemDetails:

```
public async Task AddServiceResponsesAsync(List<ServiceResponse> responses)
        {
            HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

            string uri = _configuration.GetConnectionString("web-api-uri-base-adress");

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);

            JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create();
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, responses);

            StringContent content = new StringContent(stringWriter.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync("service-responses", content);

                    var detailedError = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ProblemDetails>();
}
```

Its seems to me I'm doing something wrong. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Your main project is Blazor Wasm but your libraries reference EFCore and Dapper?  That seems odd alrerady. So, what is the setup? Do you generate client code with NSwagger or similar?

Comment: Blazor app reference a library that uses EFCore, what's seems odd about it? It's a library that has classes that acts services, and they are reused in other apps in a solution like a worker.

Comment: A Blazor Wasm app can't reach a (normal) database. Only Sqlite afaik.

Comment: You're right. But it's not the problem at this case. Blazor app uses the classes that don't use EFCore types from the library.

Comment: My main project is just a web api, that serves the blazor app.

Comment: Yes, that's why you should detail that. In which part(s) do you want to use the ErrorDetails, and how exactly?

Comment: And the client app should not have (indirect) dependencies on EF Core, Dapper or MVC. I think a better architecture might make your problem go away.

Comment: Thank you for helping me here H H with clearing up my question. I have added an excerpt from the library's code where ProblemDetails are used.

Comment: H H, what would be a good architectural solution/pattern for not having indirect deps in client of EFCore, MVC and such?

Comment: H H, still I think architecture won't solve a problem of having a ProblemDetails reference in blazor app. The ProblemDetails are present in the mvc shared framework.

Comment: Hi, I created a small library some time ago to handle this situation. Might help: https://github.com/Jimmys20/ProblemDetails

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos - that looks nice, but I think the hand-written classes is what some might want to avoid. That's why I asked about NSwag.

Comment: @michaelfromsomeplace - there are docs and samples for Blazor + Clean Architecture, start there.

Comment: @H H, I mistakenly took NSwag for Swagger. I am not familiar with NSwag, but from what I just read It seems like a possible solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I presume from your question that you want to deserialize a ProblemDetails returned from the server in your Blazor Wasm Client project so you can then inspect the ProblemDetails on the client and perform actions accordingly.

The key thing to remember is that the data returned from the server is simply Json that has been serialized from a ProblemDetails class.

Therefore, any class that has the same properties will be suitable for deserialization.

My solution has been to create a ClientProblemDetails class:

```
public class ClientProblemDetails
{
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; } = default!;

    [JsonPropertyName("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; } = default!;

    [JsonPropertyName("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; } = default!;

    [JsonPropertyName("detail")]
    public string Detail { get; set; } = default!;

    [JsonPropertyName("instance")]
    public string Instance { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Then, if the response from the server is BadRequest deserialize into a ClientProblemDetails and then pass that around the client app.  In this way, you do not need to reference the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App framework from your client.

```
if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
    ClientProblemDetails clientProblemDetails = httpResponse.Content
        .ReadFromJsonAsync<ClientProblemDetails>();

    // Pass clientProblemDetails around the client as you wish
    // or throw a custom "ApiCallException", so can catch
    // exceptions from higher up the stack and inspect with
    // ex.ProblemDetails.Type, etc.
    // e.g.:
    throw new ApiCallException(clientProblemDetails);
}

class ApiCallException : Exception
{
    public ClientProblemDetails ProblemDetails { get; }

    public ApiCallException(ClientProblemDetails details) : base(details.Title)
    {
        ProblemDetails = details;
    }

}
```